# SQL - Trigger is invalid and failed re-validation

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

When a user creates an application for the table 'application' I want a copy placed into the table 'application_history'. I've tried creating a trigger and get the error that is in the title.

```
create or replace TRIGGER create_history AFTER INSERT ON application
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
insert into application_history values (:new.arn, :new.srn, :new.job_id, :new.application_status);
END;
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: If whatever application/ interface you use to create the trigger does not show you the compilation errors, you can query `user_errors` to see them.  You can type `show errors` in `SQL*Plus` or any tool that supports that particular `SQL*Plus` command.  That is much easier to debug than a runtime error saying that your trigger is invalid.  My guess is that your `insert` statement is incorrect because the `application_history` table has more than 4 columns but that is just a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Justin suspected, you seem to be having more than 4 columns in application_history. Either provide values for all columns or specify columns lie 'insert into table1 (col1, col2) values (1,2)'

It worked for me after adding extra column 'hist_id'(just to give you an idea) ...

```
create table application (arn number, srn number, job_id number, application_status char(1) );

create table application_history (hist_id number, arn number, srn number, job_id number, application_status char(1) );

create or replace TRIGGER create_application_history AFTER INSERT ON application
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
  insert into application_history values (1, :new.arn, :new.srn, :new.job_id, :new.application_status);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a `/` at the end. So:

```
create or replace TRIGGER create_history AFTER INSERT ON application
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
insert into application_history values (:new.arn, :new.srn, :new.job_id, :new.application_status);
END;
/
```